# Alternate stylesheets not working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I need some help diagnosing a CSS problem in Chrome.   I'm not even sure how to diagnose this issue.   I'm just wondering what the next steps should be.

As far as solutions go, I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825248/enable-disable-stylesheet-using-javascript-in-chrome) but it's not very clear.  I have also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686291/alternate-stylesheets-dont-work-unless-i-disable-all-of-them-first) (disabling all styles and then enabling one) but it's not working.   I don't think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472352/external-css-styles-cant-be-accessed-in-google-chrome) applies because we're not pulling from external domains so it's not a cross-domain issue.

The problem:

It appears that Chrome is ignoring our alternate stylesheet definitions.   In our application we use alternate stylesheets and a Javascript routine to change the background color.   This code **was working**, and is **still working** in Firefox and IE, but at some point it stopped working in Chrome.   The stylesheets are defined like this:

```
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" title="white" property="stylesheet" href="/myapp/css/layer.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="alternate stylesheet" title="silver" property="stylesheet" href="/myapp/css/medium.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="alternate stylesheet" title="grey" property="stylesheet" href="/myapp/css/dark.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="alternate stylesheet" title="beige" property="stylesheet" href="/myapp/css/beige.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="alternate stylesheet" title="green" property="stylesheet" href="/myapp/css/green.css" />
```

The original body definition here:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #282828;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff url(../images/header-bg.jpg) center top no-repeat;
    min-width: 1024px;
}
```

is supposed to be overridden with (for example) this, in one of the alternate stylesheets:

```
body {
    background: url("../images/header-bg-dark.jpg") no-repeat center top #919194;
}
```

But this is not working in Chrome.  I've tried the following:

1) Traced through the JS code and verified that the CSS sheets are getting enabled/disabled correctly:

```
        if (document.styleSheets.item(i).href.indexOf("medium") > -1) {
            document.styleSheets.item(i).disabled = false;
        } else if (document.styleSheets.item(i).href.indexOf("dark") > -1
                || document.styleSheets.item(i).href.indexOf("beige") > -1
                || document.styleSheets.item(i).href.indexOf("green") > -1) {
            document.styleSheets.item(i).disabled = true;
        }
```

2) Looked at the computed styles, and only the base style is showing - it's like Chrome is ignoring the other styles.

3) Tried removing `alternate` from the `rel="alternate stylesheet"` part of the definitions.

4) Tried removing the `title` from the base definition (layer.css).

Anyone have any other ideas?   If I find a solution I'll post it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer turned out to be removing the "title" attribute AND removing the "alternate" part of the stylesheet definition.    So the stylesheets are now linked like this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" property="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/css/medium.css"/>" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" property="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/css/dark.css"/>" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" property="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/css/beige.css"/>" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" property="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/css/green.css"/>" />
```

No idea why the original definitions didn't work but the new ones work and can be turned on and off with JS, which is what we needed.

Comment: This unfortunately also prevents firefox from allowing the user to select the style sheet they want to apply under View->Page Style.  But I confirm that this is necessary to get chrome to switch stylesheets through javascript.